# Position Highcharts label to right side

Tags: charts, highcharts

I have a basic chart with a custom label, eg:

```
labels: {
  items: [{
    html: 'Testing Label',
    style: {
      left: '50px',
      top: '50px'
    }
  }]
}
```

This works, but I'd like to position the label from the right side, I tried doing:

```
style: {
  right: '50px',
  top: '50px'
}
```

but this doesn't work...

JsFiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/0ze2u47h/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `right` property is not supported in `chart.labels`. For more complex configuration you can render the label using `SVGRenderer`:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var chart = this,
          renderer = chart.renderer;

          var label = this.renderer.label('Test label', null, 100).add();
          label.attr({
            x: chart.plotWidth + chart.plotLeft - label.width
          });  
      }
    }
  }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/aob1e197/

The advantage of rendering labels via `renderer` (not via constructor options) is that you can access parameters of the already created chart and label (`chart.plotWidth`, `chart.plotLeft`, `label.width` in this case).

---

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to make it stay on the right when resizing the window/chart ?

Comment: Sure, you just need to move the positioning code to the `render` event. **Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/a3dLogtL/